# Change Linux framebuffer background color

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, framebuffer, vesa

My question is about the linux kernel. When framebuffer device initializes (I guess it is **vesafb**), the screen is filled with black color. How can I change that color? What file should I edit? I guess it is something in **drivers/video/**.

I only know about changing console background (**drivers/tty/vt/vt.c**), but this is not what I need. VGA Console is turned off.

In case my description is not clear I have a [video](http://youtu.be/HvrIP1Gsk5k) that shows my system bootup in a virtual machine. After the kernel is loaded QEMU window changes it's size to 640x480 and becomes completely black (0:03-0:04). This is what I want to modify. After it my init is started. It outputs text to framebuffer and then dies, causing kernel panic and reboot in 1sec. Then everything starts over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console implementation in `vt.c` started out as a VGA console once upon a time, but it is now used for all consoles.
(The 'attribute byte' is mapped to whatever the underlying hardware driver actually supports.)

Change the initialization of `vc_def_color` in `vc_init()`.

Since version 3.12, this can also be changed with the kernel parameter `vt.color`.

Comment: I changed it to `vc->vc_def_color = 0x07;`, but no result.
By the way it works, if I enable VGA Console, but the result is generally the same: in the very beginning the screen is filled with black color.

Comment: `0x07` is the old default. Before the GPU driver is initialized, you get the text mode set by the BIOS, which always has black background.

Comment: Okay. Does this mean that the kernel doesn't even have the screen filling code? If so, I need to add it.  

Still someone is filling the screen (see my video at 0:07, the screen is cleared from old data), maybe it is BIOS.

Comment: The kernel fills the screen when the GPU driver is initialized.

Comment: Could you please tell the exact name of function that fills the screen?